# Optimise mysql self join overlapping date range

Tags: mysql, optimization

I want to find id of the bookings that are overlapped each other.
Each booking belongs to 1 car and it always has **start** and **end**.

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE booking (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  car_id int(11),
  start datetime,
  end datetime,
  primary key(id)
);

CREATE INDEX car_start_end on booking (car_id, start, end);
```

I want to return all the bookings that are overlapped with another booking. Display in pair in each row. E.g: if **booking1** overlapped with **booking2** and **booking3**, it must be shown as 2 pairs

```
+------------+----------+
|   id1      |  id2     |
+------------+----------+
| booking1   | booking2 |
| booking1   | booking3 |
+------------+----------+
```

- Note that both booking must be on the same car.
- No duplicate pairs. E.g if **booking1** and **booking2** has already been retrieved, there should not be another pair with **booking2** and **booking1**.

Example a duplicated booking (showing the full booking details):

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id1  |     start1          | end1                | car_id | id2 |       start2        |          end2       |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+---------------------------+---------------------+
|  1   | 2019-01-01 12:00:00 | 2019-01-01 15:00:00 |   1    |  2  | 2019-01-01 14:00:00 | 2019-01-01 16:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

My current sql query:

```
SELECT b1.id, b2.id from booking b1
INNER JOIN booking b2 ON b1.car_id = b2.car_id
  -- condition for overlapping detection
  AND b1.start < b2.end
  AND b1.end > b2.start

  -- remove self overlap
  AND b1.id < b2.id;
```

I also have index for:

- `(car_id, start, end)`
- `id`.

However I am not really satisfy with the result where I try with 1million records and it takes forever to run.

Anw to improve ?
I am using mysql 5.6 on my local.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/683f77/2)

Edit:
Update [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=df318831b1bec3558ff28737176b728a) with 1000 random bookings data.

Comment: Use WHERE EXISTS.

Comment: Can you please specify more ?

Comment: Do you need 1) the list of bookings which have at least one overlapping? 2) the list of booking pairs which are overlapped?

Comment: I do need to have each row the booking id that are overlapped each other. So booking1 and booking2 overlap then I need each row both booking1's id and booking2's id. If I understand your question correctly.

Comment: English is not my native... is it var. 1 or 2?

Comment: number 2 is correct

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Can you predict the percent of bookings which are overlapped? Does it is low (individual random pairs as a result of misprint, for example) or it is relatively high (such overlapping is a norma)? And additionally specify MySQL server version - does it is 8+, or 5+ only...

Comment: Hey @Akina, I can not predict the number of record. Update the question with the fiddle.

Comment: While 'minimal', a data set comprising just two records is unlikely to be 'representative'. Consider extending it a little, and providing a desired result to suit.

Comment: Also, you can't seriously have a million records in a 1-day window. In the US, even Hertz only has ca. 330,000 cars for rent each day.

Comment: Hey @Strawberry 1millions are for bookings over a few years, but in the actual query there are some limits to the start of bookings so the total booking that needs to be processed is around 10000.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following; a data set of ca. 8000 rows comprising 100 cars rented for between 1 and 6 days over the course of a year...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bookings;

CREATE TABLE bookings
(booking_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,car_id INT NOT NULL
,booking_start DATE
,booking_end DATE
);

INSERT INTO bookings VALUES
(1,1,'2020-01-01','2020-01-02');

INSERT INTO bookings 
SELECT NULL,RAND()*100,'2020-01-01'+INTERVAL (1 + RAND()*330) DAY,NULL FROM bookings;
-- REPEAT ABOVE UNTIL YOU HAVE CA. 8000 rows --

UPDATE bookings SET booking_end = booking_start + INTERVAL (1 + RAND()*5) DAY;

ALTER TABLE bookings ADD INDEX(car_id,booking_start,booking_end);

SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT x.* -- yes, I'm still using a very old version of MySQL
                        FROM bookings x 
                        JOIN bookings y 
                          ON y.booking_id > x.booking_id 
                         AND y.car_id = x.car_id 
                         AND y.booking_end > x.booking_start 
                         AND y.booking_start <= x.booking_end
                       WHERE x.booking_start BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-01-01';
+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+
| booking_id | car_id | booking_start | booking_end |
+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+
|          2 |     85 | 2020-08-04    | 2020-08-05  |
|          3 |     69 | 2020-11-24    | 2020-11-27  |
|          4 |     89 | 2020-06-05    | 2020-06-10  |
|          5 |     69 | 2020-01-08    | 2020-01-12  |
...
|       8122 |     36 | 2020-04-07    | 2020-04-11  |
|       8123 |     36 | 2020-11-02    | 2020-11-05  |
+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+
4195 rows in set (1.57 sec)
```

1.5 seconds seems reasonable to me. I admit the EXPLAIN for the above doesn't look great but I have to confess I'm stuck on how to improve it...

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------+--------+---------+---------------+------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys             | key    | key_len | ref           | rows | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------+--------+---------+---------------+------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | x     | ALL  | PRIMARY,booking_id,car_id | NULL   | NULL    | NULL          | 8192 | Using where; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | y     | ref  | PRIMARY,booking_id,car_id | car_id | 4       | test.x.car_id |   81 | Using where; Distinct        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------+--------+---------+---------------+------+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I only came up with the following, which drops information, the *other* booking:

```
SELECT b1.id from booking b1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM booking b2
             WHERE b1.car_id = b2.car_id
             AND b1.start < b2.end
             AND b2.start < b1.end
             AND b1.id < b2.id);
```

The following would give *all* overlapping bookings, but not paired. However 3 bookings could overlap - at the same time even.

```
SELECT b1.id from booking b1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM booking b2
             WHERE b1.car_id = b2.car_id
             AND b1.start < b2.end
             AND b2.start < b1.end);
```